# will a 600W PSU power the following?

Tags: power-supply, hardware-rec, computer-building

I was wondering if a 600W PSU (power supply unit) is good enough to run the following:

- Core i3
- 2 medium quality video cards
- 2 or 3 hard drives
- 4GB ram

Comment: Which video card(s) are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PSUs tend to vary widely in quality (particularly at the low end), and depending on the video card, current rating may be important as well. Some cheap PSUs may put out much less than their rated power at full load, and others advertise a high power output but can't handle the current draw that some modern video cards incur.

Most 600W PSUs of reasonable quality should be fine with what you describe, though.

Comment: 80+ certified is something to look for :)

Comment: The quality of the components used in PSUs vary, even with an 80 PLUS cert sticker.

Comment: Well of course, but it gives you a baseline to weed out the bad from the horrible.

Answer (score 2):

This heavily depends on the model of the video cards. Most will list a minimum PSU requirement. You should be content with 600w if the cards are on par with HD 4850's or less.

I'd have a look at Newegg's [Power Supply Calculator](http://educations.newegg.com/tool/psucalc/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

I usually refer to [this PSU calculator](http://www.extreme.outervision.com/psucalculatorlite.jsp) and [this PSU brand guide list](http://www.pcmech.com/forum/computer-hardware/208143-what-power-supply-should-i-get-how-many-watts-who-made-guide-inside.html)

Answer (score 0):

I bet you could run that system on a 400W with no problems.