# Power Requirements for my setup. 

Tags: upgrade, power-supply, gpu

I understand that sometimes there may be a situation where the PSU is way more than required but in this case of mine, I'm not too sure.

Sometimes when I play games, my computer will crash and restarts itself, 10 minutes into the game. Once I received a message that says something like the power is overheating or something like that.

I have a 500W PSU. I have:

- 1x Internal DVD writer
- 1x SATA 250GB HD
- 1x Nvidia 8500 GT
- 2GB RAM.

As I'm planning to get an additional 250GB SATA HD, I wonder if I need to increase my PSU as well -- in full knowledge of the previous crashes experienced before.

Should I upgrade my PSU to 650W perhaps, or is that excessive?

Comment: An additional hard drive won't really drain the PSU that much. What I would do is check that your CPU isn't overheating.

Comment: I second Randolph's comment, this sounds like a heat problem, not a power problem. Make sure all your fans are spinning and not covered in dust. This could be the GPU overheating as well, so be sure  to check that fan too.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://superuser.com/questions/209955/will-a-600w-psu-power-the-following

Comment: @Richard, I think there might be more going on here, than just his PSU, so I'd advise against closing for now

Comment: @IvoFlipse: Sort of disagree: the answer here is use one (or more) of the online calculators (as answered on other Qs) to see what is needed. I sort of agree: they might come back saying 500W is enough :-)

Comment: Thanks all for your assistance and Richard, I'll be sure to take note of the online calculator. Thing is, I'm pretty sure that 500W suffices but that GPU glitch (whenever I play full screen games) set doubts settling within me. Appreciate all responses and for now, I'm getting the HD without a PSU change -- and we'll see how it goes. ; )

Comment: Voted to close.  This question is far too specific for this website, and you could answer this yourself with little research.  Consider using a PSU calculator like http://educations.newegg.com/tool/psucalc/index.html and also, adding a hard drive or GPU will draw much more power.  Components like RAM do not.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the crashing issue - it's possible that the error message about power was just a red herring. You might want to check out [HW Monitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html) to see if you can spot any overheating or other anomalies.

Comment: I'm sorry Kara, but what is a red herring???

Comment: My bad, I'm addicted to obscure phrases! Basically it's when something draws your attention away from the real culprit with a clue that doesn't actually help you find the problem. Windows loves to give me error messages that are completely misleading. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring